# Get page through database, but based on the URL

Tags: nginx

I have a site with the URL looking like this:

`http://example.com/index.php?id=1` - I want to turn that into `http://example.com/1-page-title-goes-here`. I do not want a redirect, because nobody knows it's `index.php?id=1` yet, because the site has not launched yet.

The `id=1` determines what the page should load. If `id=1`, it will do a SELECT from the database on that ID, then display the appropriate information on the page. Farely simple and does the job really well.

I am running Nginx on my server, which I assume would be the way to go with this..? But I am not sure. From what I can see around on the web, the rewrite rule would check the first digit(s) after `/` and before `-`, then do the database lookup based on that. However, doesn't that mean you could type anything after the `-` and it would still be a legit link? Like: `http://example.com/1-anything-can-go-here-and-it-would-not-matter`. Am I right?

Which approach would be the best? The rewrite to check the first digit(s) would work, but what about the last part of the URL? What is the best approach of doing this? Thanks in advance!

EDIT: I just noticed Stackoverflow works like this. If I add anything after `http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32848332/get-page-through-database-but-based-on-the-url` it will change it back to the original URL. Same happens if I remove something from the URL.

Comment: The best to leave it to backend

Comment: Yes, If you are searching just by id, then doesn't matters what you put after the - ...If you want, you can search by both, ID and URI

Comment: @GabrielRodriguez I would like to have it exactly like on Stackoverflow. It checks both the ID and the title, then changes title if it doesn't match like it's supposed to.